# what are Steps to add Article Search in community portal to search Knowledge Base Search

Tags: knowledge, community

I have already purchased license for my community portal than now i want to know all the steps where i can use it on my community portal.(I want to use Article Search in my community portal homepage as i used it on customer portal where any one can search only knowledgebase)

Comment: Kumar, this looks similar to your other question. If a question receives no answers it's likely too vague and unclear to other users. You can edit it to update with a more extensive description. That'll get your question to the first page again, making new questions which are so closely related will only pollute the site. If this is a separate question, do please update both to make it show clearly how they are differ and what they are truly about.